# PowerShell - Set default proxy configuration for all PS CmdLets

Tags: powershell-v4.0

I can get and set proxy settings for a `WebClient` object and make outbound calls.

I can also supply `-Proxy` and `-ProxyCredential` to individual CmdLets, but how can I just set a global default so CmdLets don't need the extra arguments?

Thanks

Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://joshcodev.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/powershell-set-a-proxy/,

`$global:PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
        'Invoke-RestMethod:Proxy'='http://proxyServer:proxyPort'
        'Invoke-WebRequest:Proxy'='http://proxyServer:proxyPort'
        '*:ProxyUseDefaultCredentials'=$true
    }`

Comment: Use this. Is supported custom proxy in powershell: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Proxy-Settings-for-Chocolatey

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about Powershell in general, not Chocolatey. Also, those IE settings can't be set in all environments (i.e. locked down enterprise)